# How to add satellite-menu on my project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, dependencies

I'm working with old project at my work, and i don't know how to add satellite-menu https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu , and it's project consist of several projects. So, i'm working in Eclipse, and i have old source code.
I imported all of folders in my projects, and everything works good, exclude 1 folder - satellite-menu. As i understood, it's a library i writed here. So, when i try to import it as a project i have a Error:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\Users\Vladimir\workspace\satellite-menu\bin\satellite-menu.jar'

Folder from `GitHub` doesn't have a `jar` file, when another of project's folder does.

This is a part of my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.wtfmagazine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="300"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/menu"
        sat:satelliteDistance="130dp"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90" />
```

So, how do i can to attach this menu to this project.
I tried to create .`jar` from this folder - doesn't work.

Comment: download jar from here http://06peng.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/satellite-menu/bin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is add satellite project as a library: project->properties->android->is library